# Passing input parameters to controller method Html.BeginForm

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, html.beginform

I realise this is extremely elemetry but I would like to pass a text box value to a controller method when using `Html.BeginForm`

this is the what I tried so far

**cshtml**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("GetPassword", "Home"))
{
    <div id="panEmailForgotPassword">
        <h3 style="margin: 0;">
            Please enter your email address</h3>
        <br />
        <table style="width: 57%; padding-bottom: 10px; height: 126px;">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label style="width: 110px;">
                        Email address:</label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.EmailForgotPassword, new { name = "txtEmailForgotPassword" })
                </td>
            </tr>
```

**controller method**

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult GetPassword(string txtEmailForgotPassword)
    {
        ViewModel model = new ViewModel();

        model.VerifyUserExists(txtEmailForgotPassword);
        return View(model);
    }
```

txtEmailForgotPassword returns a null value.

How would I do this correctly?

Arian

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I dont think there is need to pass single string paramater, rather you can pass your whole model from view

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult GetPassword(YourModel yourmodel)
    {
        ViewModel model = new ViewModel();

        model.VerifyUserExists(yourmodel.EmailForgotPassword);
        return View(model);
    }
```

Comment: ya no problem. everybody starts from nothing ;)

Comment: But i want one favour, ask your team to lose 1st test against our team hahaha ;)

Comment: Oh sure. I will talk to the captain. We are very close :-)